# Attempted to load class from namespace did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Tags: php, cassandra, namespaces, symfony

I'm using a Cassandra class in my code and this error is always showing up "Attempted to load class from namespace did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?" here are my codes

DefaultController

```
<?php

namespace Acme\SampleBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Cassandra;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
public function indexAction()
{
    $con = new Cassandra\Timestamp();

    echo $con;
}
}
```

Timestap.php

```
<?php

/**
* Copyright 2015-2016 DataStax, Inc.
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/

namespace Cassandra;

/**
* A PHP representation of the CQL `timestamp` datatype
*/
final class Timestamp implements Value
{
/**
 * Creates a new timestamp from either unix timestamp and microseconds or
 * from the current time by default.
 *
 * @param int $time Unix timestamp
 * @param int $usec Microseconds
 */
public function __construct($time = null, $usec = null) {}

/**
 * The type of this timestamp.
 *
 * @return Type
 */
public function type() {}

/**
 * Unix timestamp.
 *
 * @return int seconds
 * @see time
 */
public function time() {}

/**
 * Microtime from this timestamp
 *
 * @param bool $get_as_float Whether to get this value as float
 *
 * @return float|string Float or string representation
 * @see microtime
 */
public function microtime($get_as_float = false) {}

/**
 * Converts current timestamp to PHP DateTime.
 *
 * @return \DateTime PHP representation
 */
public function toDateTime() {}

/**
 * Returns a string representation of this timestamp.
 *
 * @return string timestamp
 */
public function __toString() {}
}
```

I don't know what's wrong in my code, I'm a newbie using Cassandra and symfony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you defining the keyspace in the configuration file?

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/M6Web/CassandraBundle#configuration-reference)

Comment: I'm not using any keyspace for now, I just want to explore the Cassandra in symfony but I can't do that because of this error message "Attempted to load class "Timestamp" from namespace "Cassandra". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?"

Comment: The class [Timestamp](https://datastax.github.io/php-driver/api/Cassandra/class.Timestamp/) is just a type of data that can be stored in Cassandra, not a value per-se.

If you want to use PHP, there is a tutorial [here](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-apache-cassandra-and-php) that can be helpful